# Repeating similar text that is tedious to manually type using Python

Tags: python, csv

I am creating a program that reads lines from a CSV file. The only issue I am encountering is that I have so many fields it is tedious to create a line for each variable. I will give you an example:

```
f1 = fields[0]
f2 = fields[1]
f3 = fields[2]
f4 = fields[3]
f5 = fields[4]
f6 = fields[5]
f7 = fields[6]
f8 = fields[7]
f9 = fields[8]

#... all the way to ...
f92 = fields[91]
```

I have tried to find an easy way to use it by copying and pasting, but it still takes over half an hour to do something of this scale.

Is there any functions or online tools I could use to shorten this process (or an alternative way of writing this code)?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Why would anyone want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish with it at the end?

Comment: @Aganju I am trying to read a CSV file with many fields and print them all (print code not included), do you want a source?

Comment: Why assign the fields to separate variables at all? If the variable names are formulaic as you show, then they contain no information so just use indexing to access the field values. Perhaps we need the context that you alluded to?

Comment: @mhawke I will edit with a source.

Comment: If you just want to print them, do this: `print(*fields, sep=' ')`

Comment: Its okay to show an example with just a few columns. No need for writer's cramp.

Comment: Do you need to do something unique and special with each field, or are there large sections of `fields` (e.g. `fields[10:60]`) where every field needs to be treated in the same way? For the latter, use a loop.

Comment: Knowing how to use arrays is one of the very basics for imperative programming. This question doesn't seem like a good fit here, it shows little research effort, is not clear, and isn't that useful, since anyone with even introductory programming experience knows how to use arrays. Rather than Stack Overflow, I'd recommend starting with a beginner textbook. Some of them are freely available online, like [A Byte of Python](https://python.swaroopch.com/). If you're willing to spend a half-hour typing, consider spending a few hours learning why you don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, we can use Python for this:

```
for i in range(92):
    print('f{} = fields[{}]'.format(i+1,i))
```

Prints:

```
f1 = fields[0]
f2 = fields[1]
f3 = fields[2]
f4 = fields[3]
f5 = fields[4]
f6 = fields[5]
f7 = fields[6]
f8 = fields[7]
f9 = fields[8]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can produce the text using Python with

```
print('\n'.join(f"f{i+1} = fields[{i}]" for i in range(len(fields))))
```

You can paste it in your file or just run it with

```
exec('\n'.join(f"f{i+1} = fields[{i}]" for i in range(len(fields))))
```

Though you could get the same effect more efficiently with,

```
globals.update({f"f{i+1}": fields[i] for i in range(len(fields))})
```

But this is pointless, since you can just use

```
f = [None, *fields]
```

to get the 1-based index. Then you can use `f[1]` in place of `f1`, etc.

The `[]`-indexed structure is a lot more convenient to work with than 92 individual variables anyway.